# Access 2016 - Return TRUE if Item exists in Table, False if Item is Missing

Tags: sql, ms-access, left-join, ms-access-2016

Ok, I have two tables.

1 lists a bunch of courses and their details.
1 lists a bunch of curriculums and their associated connections.

I need to create a query that will list the curriculum name, LIST ALL COURSES, and then indicate if the course is in the Curriculum (TRUE) or not present (FALSE).

Here is what I have tried so far.

Left Outer Join for courses table since I want ALL the courses compared to the curriculums

Count number of curriculum ids for each course - DOESN'T WORK ONLY RETURNS '1' VALUES; AND ONLY SHOWS COURSES IN THE CURRICULUM

Finding Differences Between Two Tables - DOESN'T WORK, ONLY SHOWS VALUES WITH NO CURRICULUMS.

Tried an IIF(IS NULL) calculation - DOESN'T WORK ONLY RETURNS 'TRUE' VALUES; AND ONLY SHOWS COURSES IN THE CURRICULUM.

This should be easy.  Can someone help me create the query.  Basically put I need all values from BOTH tables showing up and then showing where the value is NULL in relation to the courses.

Table 1:

```
COURSE ID    COURSE NAME
1              ENGLISH
2              FRENCH
3              DRAWING
4              SKETCHING
```

Table 2

```
Curriculum ID          Curriculum NameID        Course ID
1                      Senior   (actually #)       1
2                      Senior                      3
3                      Junior                      1
4                      Junior                      2
5                      Junior                      3
```

Results

```
Curriculum Name          Course Name             In Curriculum
Senior                     English                True
Senior                     French                 False
Senior                     Drawing                True
Senior                     Sketching              False
Junior                     English                True
Junior                     French                 True
Junior                     Drawing                True
Junior                     Sketching              False
```

TJ

Comment: Sample data showing the desired end result would help us better understand your requirements.

Comment: I tried to add tables...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you essentially have a many-to-many relationship between courses & curriculums (a course could appear on several curriculums, and a curriculum could contain several courses), I would suggest structuring your data in the following manner:

#### Table: Courses

```
+-------+-----------+
| Co_ID |  Co_Desc  |
+-------+-----------+
|     1 | English   |
|     2 | French    |
|     3 | Drawing   |
|     4 | Sketching |
+-------+-----------+
```

#### Table: Curriculums

```
+-------+---------+
| Cu_ID | Cu_Desc |
+-------+---------+
|     1 | Junior  |
|     2 | Senior  |
+-------+---------+
```

#### Junction Table: Curriculum_Courses

```
+----------+----------+
| CC_Cu_ID | CC_Co_ID |
+----------+----------+
|        1 |        1 |
|        1 |        2 |
|        1 |        3 |
|        2 |        1 |
|        2 |        3 |
+----------+----------+
```

Then, your query is relatively easy to construct as you can use a combination of a cross-join and left-join in the following manner:

```
select 
    t.cu_desc as [Curriculum Name], 
    t.co_desc as [Course Name], 
    not cc_cu_id is null as [In Curriculum]
from
    (select * from curriculums, courses) t left join curriculum_courses u on
    t.cu_id = u.cc_cu_id and
    t.co_id = u.cc_co_id
order by
    t.cu_id, t.co_id
```